# Terminal: how to use `at`?

Tags: terminal, high-sierra, command-line, unix, mojave

Could someone provide some example usages for the `at` command? I'm finding the `man` super confusing.

```
$ man at
```

For example, if we wanted to run a command 10 minutes from now, can this be done using `at`? (and without using `sleep`)

Comment: As of macOS 12.2.1, the best write-up I've seen to answer this is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478840/193772

Answer (score 5):

The time spec for "10 minutes from now" is `now +10 minutes`. For example,

```
echo 'open ~' | at now +10 minutes
```

However, the `at` system is disabled by default in macOS, as mentioned in the `at` man page:

```
IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
     Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon periodically
     invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default.  See atrun(8) for infor-
     mation about enabling atrun.
```

The `atrun` man page says that you need to run

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Comment: See also https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3141259 and https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770927/is-at-broken-in-osx

Answer (score 0):

> I Use the `at` command when I need to do some heavy processing on
>   data, which I want to have executed during the night, when I am not
>   behind my computer. Of course I could start the process just after I
>   leave, but this is something I tend to forget.
>
> The result of the command is not different from regularly execution of
>   the script or command.
>   
> @Bernhard

**What it does**

excerpt from `at` man page

```
NAME
       at, batch, atq, atrm - queue, examine or delete jobs for later execution

DESCRIPTION
       at  and  batch  read  commands  from  standard  input or a specified file
       which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.
```

**Usage**

The usage of the tools:

```
Usage: at [-V] [-q x] [-f file] [-mldbv] timespec ...
       at [-V] [-q x] [-f file] [-mldbv] -t time
       at -c job ...
       atq [-V] [-q x]
       atrm [-V] job ...
       batch
```

`at` includes 4 commands (`at`, `atq`, `atrm`, and `batch`). You use `at` and `batch` to schedule the jobs, `atq` to see what's scheduled, and `atrm` to remove a job prior to it running.

`$ at -f <cmd> timspec`

**Timespec**

The time to run the at job can be specified in different ways.

excerpt form at man page

> At allows fairly complex time specifications, extending the POSIX.2
>   standard. It accepts times of the form HH:MM to run a job at a
>   specific time of day. (If that time is already past, the next day is
>   assumed.) You may also specify mid‐ night, noon, or teatime (4pm) and
>   you can have a time-of-day suffixed with AM or PM for running in the
>   morning or the evening. You can also say what day the job will be run,
>   by giving a date in the form month-name day with an optional year, or
>   giving a date of the form MMDD[CC]YY, MM/DD/[CC]YY, DD.MM.[CC]YY or
>   [CC]YY-MM-DD. The specification of a date must follow the
>   specification of the time of day. You can also give times like now +
>   count time-units, where the time- units can be minutes, hours, days,
>   or weeks and you can tell at to run the job today by suffixing the
>   time with today and to run the job tomorrow by suffixing the time with
>   tomorrow.

**Examples**

Say you have this shell script.

```
$ cat mycrontest.sh

#!/bin/bash
 echo "It is now $(date +%T) on $(date +%A)"
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./mycrontest.sh
It is now 18:37:42 on Friday
```

Sample at job submissions:

```
$ at -f mycrontest.sh  10pm tomorrow
job 14 at Sun Jul  8 22:00:00 2007

$ at -f mycrontest.sh 2:00 tuesday
job 15 at Tue Jul 10 02:00:00 2007

$ at -f mycrontest.sh 2:00 july 11
job 16 at Wed Jul 11 02:00:00 2007

$ at -f mycrontest.sh 2:00 next week
job 17 at Sat Jul 14 02:00:00 2007
```

Credits to @slm